# Make real Splash Screen before http request

Tags: c#, asp.net, splash-screen

I need to make a  C# splash screen that will be started before default.aspx is called.

When I browse to my URL, I can see the IE 8.0 message `waiting for http://xxxxx` with a blank screen, and in some time my first page is fully loaded. How can I handle\intercept that message, in order to show my splash screen until the connection is established?

I've tried using HttpListener but it doesn't seem to be the right way.

Comment: Anything you do will invariably increase the time it takes to load.  'Loading' screens are inherently a bad idea. I would suggest reading [this page from Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) on improving load times.

Comment: @Styne666 - Loading a splashscreen plus the real page does take more real time than just that real page, but the *perceived* time is less as the user sees that "it is doing something", instead of waiting on a blank screen.

Comment: @Hans The best feedback that a page is doing something is seeing that it is (progressively) loading the content you are expecting to find.

Comment: Thanks for yours reply! I have already a splash screen , but i can't handle waiting time between browser is waiting for http:\\mypage.aspx and connection with server was established (message "done" ,at the left of IE 8.0 status bar). I don't want see blank screen to waiting a response with server. Is there some threading to handle or Can I do something inside my global.asax?

Answer (score 1):

You can't show something of your site before the browser contacts your site.

What you *can* do is have a lightweight start page (that loads quickly) at the root of your site and then redirect to a heavier "real" page.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn output buffering off to do something like you ask but the content on the "waiting code" must not be using any of the other resources being loaded. The communication will also become more chatty.

aspx-page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BufferingResponse.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Waiting...
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace BufferingResponse
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Context.Response.BufferOutput = false;

            // simulate some work...
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Response.Write("<div>Another response five seconds later...</div>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, 
Can I do Something while Main heavy page was html decoded?

If I use a response.write , I must do a redirect .
Is there no way to perform something through global.asax for example?
Regards

Comment: No, you can't do it on the server other than through buffering or using ajax.

Comment: how can I use ajax in this issue?

Comment: My Website is already ajax orientered, was performed with Ext.Net

Comment: Isn't the page the rendered in Ext.onReady()? Anything you add to the "html" page will show up until Ext.onReady. Haven't worked with Ext.Net but that's the way it pretty much works in ExtJS. My ExtJS html pages are about 500 bytes (fast to load) and then the content is rendered after the onReady.

Comment: When Ext.OnReady was fired , default page was just compiled(I think). I have already a jquery splash screen that will start in this time but my problem is before. I don't want see blank screen with browser message ("waiting for http://....") until "done". After "done" message , default was decoded and ready to use.

Comment: How big is the aspx file (only that file and no scripts) when fully loaded? If you look at Ext.net examples site theirs is about 12k which seems to be quite big but it's 3.0.4 so maybe that was how it was.

Comment: 50k ,it's not a simple default page, has silverlight content, flash content and all security handle

Comment: And talking about external process (maybe webclient app) that enquiry webserver to get some response (busy,connected) when site was compiled. In second time I could invoke an http request .

Comment: The key to have the page show content quickly is to minimize the actual html. Until the 50k is loaded there is nothing you can do.